# how do I play 3 sword attack animation properly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, game-development

-when I input my first 3 attacks, the 3 animation will only play after I click for the 4th time
-when I spam click, the 1st animation will only play after the first 3 spam clicks, after the 3 animation is finished

any help or suggestions?

```
public class swordscript : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public GameObject Sword;
     private Animator anim;
 
     private int comboStep = 0; // Current step in the combo
     private float lastComboTime = 0f; // Time when the last attack was started
     private float comboTimeout = 1.0f; // Time window for completing the combo
     private float ResetAtkCooldown = 0.5f;
 
     void Start()
     {
         // Get the Animator component from the Sword GameObject
         anim = Sword.GetComponent<Animator>();
     }
 
     void Update()
     {
         // Check if the player has clicked the mouse
         if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
         {
             
 
             // Check if we're in a combo
             if (Time.time - lastComboTime <= comboTimeout)
             {
 
                 // Increment the combo step
                 comboStep++;
 
                 // Perform the appropriate action based on the combo step
                 switch (comboStep)
                 {
                     case 1:
                         anim.SetTrigger("Attack");
                         StartCoroutine(ResetToIdle());
                         break;
                     case 2:
                         anim.SetTrigger("Attack2");
                         StartCoroutine(ResetToIdle());
                         break;
                     case 3:
                         anim.SetTrigger("Attack3");
                         StartCoroutine(ResetToIdle());
                         break;
                     default:
                         // Reset the combo if the player takes too long to complete it
                         if (comboStep > 3)
                         {
                             comboStep = 1;
                         }
                         break;
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 // Start a new combo
                 comboStep = 1;
             }
 
             // Record the time of the last attack
             lastComboTime = Time.time;
         }
     }
     IEnumerator ResetToIdle()
     {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(ResetAtkCooldown);
         comboStep = 0;
     }
 }
```

I want the animation attack to play in every click I input (like 1st click = attack, 2nd click = attack2, 3rd click = Attack2, And will reset after attack string again when I click another 3 times)

Answer (score 0):

There're numerous problems of this code that you better place a debugger out to see how your code actually works apart from your expected behavior. For instance:

the

```
// Check if we're in a combo
if (Time.time - lastComboTime <= comboTimeout) {
    // Increment the combo step
    comboStep++;
```

1. Since, unless in a double click, Time.time - lastComboTime <= comboTimeout always return false. So, it never jumps into the combo control block with a single click.
2. Right after that, comboStep set to 1, increase to 2. So it start combo at Attack2

For state control block like this, I recommend State Design Pattern. Which I learn from this quite easy to understand blog:
https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html

Good luck

*Note: you can hash trigger string for a cleaner code and a bit better performance*

```
private static readonly int attack = Animator.StringToHash("Attack");
```